# Left outer join not returning all rows in a grouping query

Tags: postgresql, join, sum

I'm trying to query all users to find the price of orders in the last month. I'm doing this on PostgreSQL. Here's a toy database to show my problem: I have a `people` table and an `orders` table. I'm trying to find the sum of orders for all people in the last month.

Here's my data:

```
select * from people;
 id |     name     
----+--------------
  1 | bobby lee
  2 | greg grouper
  3 | Hilldawg Ca
(3 rows)

select * from orders;
 id | person_id |    date    | price 
----+-----------+------------+-------
  1 |         3 | 2014-08-20 |  3.50
  2 |         3 | 2014-09-20 |  6.00
  3 |         3 | 2014-09-10 |  7.00
  4 |         2 | 2014-09-10 |  7.00
  5 |         2 | 2014-08-10 |  2.50
```

And here's the query I'm trying to write:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, sum(o.price)
FROM people p
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o
ON p.id = o.person_id
WHERE o.date between date '2014-09-01' AND date '2014-09-30'
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Here is the return I get:

```
 id |     name     |  sum  
----+--------------+-------
  2 | greg grouper |  7.00
  3 | Hilldawg Ca  | 13.00
(2 rows)
```

I'm expecting a third row, with person id 1 (bobby lee) having a sum of zero for the last month's orders (since no orders exist for bobby). What am I doing incorrectly with my query? My impression was that doing a left outer join and grouping by `people.id` means that the `people` table should set the number of rows in the output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `WHERE o.date ...` condition makes the outer join behave like an inner join, cutting out any rows of `people`that don't have at least one matching row in `orders`.

You'll have to move the condition about `o.date` from the `WHERE` clause to the joining `ON`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, coalesce(sum(o.price), 0.00) AS total
FROM people p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o
    ON  p.id = o.person_id
    AND o.date BETWEEN date '2014-09-01' AND date '2014-09-30'
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Test in: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/edf3b/3)